# HTML - Position Page Footer Based on Scroll

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` which fills the window top to bottom except for the header which is 66px tall.  The `<div>` has fixed position, so the scrolling of the page happens inside that `<div>`, not in the browser window.  If the `<div>`'s content does not reach 56px from the bottom of the `<div>`, which is the top of the footer, I want the footer to be shown at the bottom.  If the content does reach 56px from the bottom of the `<div>`, and goes past that point, I want the footer to be partially or completely hidden, depending on how far the content goes, and to show up with the content with the scroll at the bottom of the page.  This may sound sort of confusing, so here is the basic layout:

---

`How the page should look when the content does not reach the bottom:`
[image]
The footer stays visible at the bottom of the window.

---

`How the page should look when the content goes past 56px from the bottom:`
[image]
The footer is partilly pushed out of the way by the content, but will be completely revealed when the page is scrolled down.

---

`How the page should look when the content goes past the bottom:`
[image]
The footer is completely pushed off the screen, but will be revealed when the page is scrolled down.

---

I hope that this all makes sense.  I didn't think posting my code would be useful because it is mostly explained by the images.  The header, footer, and content are all `<div>`s, and the content `<div>` is the one I was talking about at the beginning of this question.  The header has fixed position, and stays in the same place when the page scrolls.

Thanks, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -155px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
footer, .push {
    height: 155px; /* '.push' must be the same height as 'footer' */
}

/*

Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait
http://ryanfait.com/

*/
```

Comment: I looked at this and it looks good, and it's not a long solution.  thanks

Comment: Would be best if you included the CSS from http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/layout.css in your answer.